# Add lines and text in a plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, text

If I have the following code:

```
data = {{2, 66.9795853828354}, {Log[300]/Log[10], 
    70.18157017698786}, {Log[600]/Log[10], 71.76921354704794}, {3, 
    72.4945695680508}, {-2.3010299956639813`, 
    54.00231502199229}, {-(Log[60]/Log[10]), 
    55.1941444178587}, {-(Log[20]/Log[10]), 56.003834022541035}, {-1, 
    56.949679030549746}, {-(Log[6]/Log[10]), 
    57.3050045190135}, {-(Log[10/3]/Log[10]), 
    57.72132372329668}, {-(Log[2]/Log[10]), 
    58.24888194249831}, {-2.3010299956639813, 
    54.03670125564749}, {-(Log[60]/Log[10]), 
    55.11571197888246}, {-(Log[20]/Log[10]), 56.17041542461532}, {-1, 
    56.71167863055032}, {-(Log[6]/Log[10]), 
    57.25059302294601}, {-(Log[10/3]/Log[10]), 
    57.70966183063876}, {-(Log[2]/Log[10]), 58.106793148660984}};


eqn = ((log10q - Log10[qref]) == 
    c1*(Tfp - Tfpref)/(c2 + (Tfp - Tfpref))); 
model = Tfp /. Solve[eqn, Tfp][[1]] // FullSimplify;
const = {Tfpref -> 57.25, qref -> 10/60 };
model2 = model /. (const // Rationalize) // FullSimplify;

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {model2, c1 > 5, c2 > 5}, {c1, c2}, 
   log10q];
```

Which plotted with the following code gives:

```
Show[{ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]},Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameStyle -> 16, ImageSize -> Large,GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8],FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {HoldForm@Log10["q (K/s)"], Row[{Subscript[T, f'], " (", Degree, " C)"}]})], Plot[nlm[log10q], {log10q, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]},(*The legends in the Epilog start here*)Epilog -> Inset[Framed[Column[{PointLegend[{Red}, {"Data"}, {LegendMarkerSize -> 15}, {LabelStyle -> 15}],LineLegend[{Blue}, {"Fit"}, {LegendMarkerSize -> 15}, {LabelStyle -> 15}]}], RoundingRadius -> 10],Scaled[{0.35, 0.8}]]]
```

[image]

Question:

How can I add text in the Figure as to create a plot similar to this (done with Paint)?:

[image: image2]

Where in the image I have two texts "Range 1" and "Range 2" as well as two red lines separating the two ranges.

Comment: Look up `Epilog` and `Prolog`, `Inset`, `Text`, `Style`. In short: `Plot[..., Epilog -> {Inset[Style["Range1", Bold, 14], <positioncontrols>], Red, Line[{firstpoint, last point}], ...}]`. I am pretty sure this has come up before on the site. Have you made it a habit to do a search of this site before posting? You could get your answers quicker that way.

Comment: You could also combine a `Graphics` object containing `Inset` and `Line`s with your plots using `Show`.

Comment: @MarcoB. Two things: 1)Yes, I looked up but I couldn't see something with text and lines together.2) I am already using `Epilog` for the Legends and I am not sure how to implement a second `Epilog` for the text and lines. Could you give me an example if you don't mind on how to do this implementation or doing it with `Graphics` or `Show`?

Comment: Just a few of the top results from a quick search here ("add text / line plot"): [Add text or descriptions to Plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83702/27951); [How to add a vertical line to a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3561/27951); [Add region-labels below x-axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/213179/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB this is very helpful and I did not find this one before. I think I should be able to solve this problem with this. Should I erase this post?

Comment: If you solve your problem, self-answers are always encouraged here. You should also be able to close your own post as a duplicate of another so they become linked and make it easier for others with the same problem to follow the breadcrumbs.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks. I am still trying to solve it. If I solve it, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
texts = MapThread[Text[Style["Range "<>#, 20, FontFamily -> Times], #2, {0, 0}, {0, 1}]&,
  {{"1", "2", "3"}, {{1, 57}, {2, 58}, {2.75, 59}}}];

epilog = {texts, 
   First @ Plot[nlm[log10q], {log10q, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]};

legend = Placed[
   LineLegend[{Red, ColorData[97][1]}, {"Data", "Fit"}, 
    Joined -> {False, True}, 
    LegendMarkers -> {Automatic, None}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Frame"], 
   Scaled[{.2, .8}]];

data2 = {{Log10[30], 64.5}, {Log10[300], 69.5}};

ListPlot[{data, data2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]], None}, 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameStyle -> 16, ImageSize -> Large, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {HoldForm@Log10["q (K/s)"], 
     Row[{Subscript[T, f'], " (", Degree, " C)"}]}), 
 Filling -> {2 -> 50},
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.008]],
 Epilog -> epilog,
 PlotLegends -> legend]
```

[image]

Comment: kglr thank you!! This is also a very nice way to solve the problem! I appreciate it !

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the suggestions of @MarcoB I was able to do it. Here's one way to do it:

```
  Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]}, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameStyle -> 16, ImageSize -> Large, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Lighter[Gray, .8], 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Bold] & /@ {HoldForm@Log10["q (K/s)"], 
      Row[{Subscript[T, f'], " (", Degree, " C)"}]})], 
 Plot[nlm[log10q], {log10q, Min[data[[All, 1]]], 
   Max[data[[All, 1]]]}],(*The legends in the Epilog start here*)
 Epilog -> {Inset[
    Framed[Column[{PointLegend[{Red}, {"Data"}, {LegendMarkerSize -> 
          15}, {LabelStyle -> 15}], 
       LineLegend[{Blue}, {"Fit"}, {LegendMarkerSize -> 
          15}, {LabelStyle -> 15}]}], RoundingRadius -> 10], 
    Scaled[{0.35, 0.8}]], 
   Rotate[Text[Style["Range 1", 20, FontFamily -> Times], {1, 57}], 
    90 Degree], 
   Style[Line[{{Log10[30], 50}, {Log10[30], 64.5}}], Red, Dashed, 
    Thickness[0.008]], 
   Rotate[Text[Style["Range 2", 20, FontFamily -> Times], {2, 58}], 
    90 Degree], 
   Style[Line[{{Log10[300], 50}, {Log10[300], 69.5}}], Red, Dashed, 
    Thickness[0.008]], 
   Rotate[Text[Style["Range 3", 20, FontFamily -> Times], {2.75, 59}],
     90 Degree]}]
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: That’s very nice! Glad you were able to piece it together! (+1)